# Why is James Bond in the working draft of the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards

I opened [the draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/), moved to [its index](https://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:Bond), searched for the word *lambda* at that page, and proceeded to successive matches until, at the 5th match, I found

> Bond
>
> James Bond, [expr.prim.lambda.capture]

What's that?

I know this is stricly not a question about code, but that stuff is the draft of the standard draft! Furthermore, James Bond appears in the index beside the totally-about-the-language [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#:Bond,James_Bond). Not sure whether I should add the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag.

I know the note at the beginning of the draft that reads

> Note: this is an early draft. It's known to be incomplet and incorrekt, and it has lots of bad formatting.

but that's exactly the point: is *James Bond* in the index a "typo" (well, a prank), or maybe I just don't know something quite crucial?

---

Based on the comments, it seems this is a not-so-infrequent case of jokes in the standard.

A follow-up question (that I don't dare asking separately) would be: *"Are these jokes retained in the actual standard?"*

Comment: So, you haven't found the My Little Pony stuff yet?

Comment: No, @sweenish is being serious: `atomic<pony> princesses = {};`

Comment: apparently because `double ohseven = .007;` (not kidding)

Comment: Because C++ is a serious language with a Standard written by people who like jokes. As opposed to (say) Java, which is just one big joke.

Comment: One more for you: [zombie brains](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:brains)! But anyway, the drafts contain a number of easter eggs to, I imagine, break up the monotony for those who have to _review the standard multiple times_ before final ratification/further discussion.

Comment: @wkl, [zombies seem to be a language-orthogonal obsession](https://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/).

Comment: [cats](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:cats) and [dogs](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:dogs)

Comment: @AdrianMole, presumably then every C++ lover should love my question and upvote it. I hope that's being the case :D

Comment: @wkl So, those are not part of a Voight-Kampff test...

Comment: @Enlico Some example from a completely different scientific problem domain https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_louse such isn't generally unusual

Comment: There is a limerick lurking in the actual standard since 1998.

Comment: To answer your updated comment - yes, these joke-y bits end up in the final versions. The limerick @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. mentioned is `When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.`, which was recently removed from the latest working draft, but was in the final C++98 standard doc on page 279 - `§ 14.7.3 part 8`. I don't have a copy of C++17 or 20 standards right now, but the final drafts of them still refer to stuff like `James Bond` and `pony`.

Comment: @AdrianMole C++ was serious language but it went too far with its new features. I prefer plain C.

Comment: @i486, why not assembly?

Answer (score 34):

It's a [joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)#Software).

Timur Doumler did [a lightning talk "ISO/IEC 14882" at CppCon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkBEAUMuFwo) where he listed this and similar jokes and easter eggs from the standard.

And yes, these are part of the official standard document, not just the draft.

Comment: Much like the status 418 I'm a teapot in the HTML standard.